# How does the == operator converts data types in JS?

Tags: javascript, types

```
var number = 2;
var string = '2';
if (number == string){
    return true;
}
```

The code above will return true. I was wondering how the == operator works. Will it convert the integer to string and then do the comparsion or the oposite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: This has been asked before, [checkout post about type coercion in JS.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/554389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering how the == operator works. Will it convert the integer to string and then do the comparison or the opposite?

No, it will convert the string to a number and then do the comparison.

You can read the exact [Abstract Equality Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) in the spec if you want.

Answer (score 0):

== operator does change the  data type.
 we can use `parseInt` in JavaScript for number and  `toString` for string

If we compare like that it always return false :-

```
var number = parseInt("2");
var string = '2';
var str=string.toString;
if (number == str){
   return TRUE;
}else{
   return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Of course that does return `FALSE` (which throws an `undefined variable error`), because you are comparing a function to a number.

Answer (score 0):

you must define the base when you use the parseInt function and use the === to compare the strict equality :

```
var number = parseInt('2', 10);
var string = '2';
return (number === string);
```

- about parseInt 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
- about === https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

Comment: Yes. But the OP neither uses `parseInt` nor `===`?